# Дружественные числа. Выход за временные рамки

Tags: c, теория-чисел

Даны два целых положительных числа M, N. Требуется найти все «дружественные»
пары чисел на отрезке [M; N]. Дружественным для числа А является такое число В, что
оно равно сумме делителей А, исключая само значение А. И наоборот, сумма делителей В,
исключая В, равняется А. A не равно B.

Input 
Со стандартного устройства ввода в первой строке через пробел вводятся два целых
положительных числа M (2<=M<=10<sup>5</sup> ) и N (2<=M<=N<=10<sup>5</sup> ).

Output
Требуется вывести все пары «дружественных» чисел, расположенные на отрезке [M; N].
Пару «дружественных» чисел (E, F) нужно выводить раньше пары «дружественных»
чисел (K, P), когда минимальный элемент пары «дружественных» чисел (E, F) меньше
минимального элемента пары «дружественных» чисел (K, P).
Число E в паре «дружественных» чисел (E, F) нужно выводить раньше числа F из этой
же пары, когда Е меньше F.
Числа в паре нужно разделять пробелом, ставить пробел после второго члена пары
не нужно.

```
Sample Input
```

210 294

```
Sample Output
```

220 284

Примечание
Попробуйте реализовать функцию getSumOfDivisors(n), которая принимает число n, а
возвращает сумму делителей числа n, кроме самого n.

Мой код

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int getSumOfDivirsors(int a)
{
    int i,p;
    p = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= a / 2; i++)
        if (a % i == 0) p = p + i;
    return p;
}
int main()
{
    int m, n, e, f, i, tr1, tr2;
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    if (m < 220) m = 220;
    if (n > 88730) n = 88730;

    for (i = m; i < n; i++)
    {
        tr1 = getSumOfDivirsors(i);
        if (tr1 <= n) {
            tr2 = getSumOfDivirsors(tr1);
            if (i == tr2 && tr1!=tr2) { printf("%d %d", tr2, tr1); printf("\n"); i = tr1; }

        }
        
    }
}
```

Выходит за временные рамки в 1с. Как можно улучшить код, чтобы укладывался в 1с ?

Comment: До 10^5 всего 5 пар [дружественных чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0). Рекомендую не заморачиваться, жестко их прошить и выбирать потом подходящие...

Comment: пустую команду в цикле убрать надо. `for (i = 2; i <= a / 2; i++)   ;`

Comment: @Harry А 10 в 5 это же 100000

Comment: Ну, значит 14 пар... Тем более! :)

Answer (score 5):

Берем функцию поиска суммы делителей

```
int getSumOfDivirsors(int a)
{
    int i,p;
    p = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= a / 2; i++)
        if (a % i == 0) p = p + i;
    return p;
}
```

и понимаем, что она на самом деле делает дармовую работу. ведь если x есть делителем a, то a/x - это тоже делитель. Поэтому, можно считать до корня квадратного и тем самым ускорить неплохо. (с линейной сложности переходим на "корень квадратный")

```
int getSumOfDivirsors(int a)
{
    int p = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(a);i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) p = p + i + a/i;
    }
    return p;
}
```

если предыдущий вариант в диапазоне 0-50000 у меня работал за 6 секунд, то с исправлениями - меньше пол секунды. До 10000 досчитал за 0.6.

**update:**

Чуточку помедитировал над функцией и нашел один случай, когда она работает не совсем верно - если исходное число - квадрат, тогда делитель, равный корню повторяется дважды. Я сильно сомневаюсь, что минусатор это увидел, но я увидел. Вот подправленный вариант.

```
int getSumOfDivirsors2(int a)
{
    int p = 1;
    int sq = sqrt(a);
    for (int i = 2; i < sq;i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) p = p + i + a/i;
    }
    if (sq*sq == a) { p = p+sq;}
    return p;
}
```

теперь результаты выдает более правильные.

Comment: `sqrt(a)` лучше вынести из цикла. Только константа, конечно, но всё же правильный обычай.

Comment: я решил проверить Ваше предположение, но обнаружил удивительное. после выноса константы, код цикла стал ... больше. Более того, даже без оптимизаций, clang сам додумался вынести вычисление sqrt за пределы цикла. Бенчмарки показали соизмеримую скорость и погрешность в несколько процентов. Скорее всего clang увидел, что у меня переменная не изменяется.

Comment: "На компилятор надейся, а сам не плошай." :) Вы правы - этот код не проблема для оптимизатора. Он понимает что `sqrt` чистая функция, а `a` константа.

Answer (score -1):

В вашем коде есть ошибка в операторе `i = tr1;`. Например для отрезка `63020 76084` ваша программа выдаст одну пару `63020 76084`, а должна выдать три `63020 76084, 66928 66992, 67095 71145`. Убирайте присвоение - это не оптимизация, а ошибка.

В остальном ваш код рабочий, но работает медленее чем мог бы. `getSumOfDivirsors` можно серьёзно ускорить.

Сумма делителей натурального числа обладает одним интересным свойством. Обозначим через `s(n)` искомую сумму. В эту сумму включается и единица и само число. Почему так сейчас станет ясно.

Пусть `n` делится на простое `p`. Тогда можем записать что `n = p^s * m`, причём `m` на `p` уже не делится. Пусть `k` делитель `m`. Какие из него можно составить делители `n`? `1 * k`, `p * k`, `p^2 * k`, ..., `p^s * k`. Их сумма равна `(1 + p + p^2 + ... + p^s) * k`. И так для любого делителя `m`. Переберём все делители `m`, для каждого сосчитаем такую сумму, все такие суммы сложим. Получится

> ```
> (1 + p + p^2 + ... + p^s) * <сумма всех делителей m> =
> = (1 + p + p^2 + ... + p^s) * s(m)
> ```

В этой сумме перечислены по одному разу все делители `n`. Значит

> ```
> s(n) = (1 + p + p^2 + ... + p^s) * s(m)
> ```

Эта формула открывает очень быстрый способ сосчитать `s(n)` по разложению `n` на простые.

Нас интересуют все делители кроме самого числа, которое в `s(n)` включено. То есть нам нужна величина `s(n) - n`.

Подробнее тут: [функция делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9).

Расчёт по этим формулам быстрее простого перебора делителей для составных `n`. Для простых `n` формула делает `sqrt(n)` проверок.

Можно сделать ещё быстрее, но и этого пока достаточно, чтобы программа уложилась в ограничения по времени с запасом.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum_of_divisors(int n) {
    int s = 1;
    int i = 2;
    int j = n;

    while (i * i <= j) {
        if (j % i == 0) {
            int f = 1;  // 1 + i + i^2 + ... + i^s
            int m = i;  // i, i^2, ..., i^s
            do {
                f += m;
                j /= i;
                m *= i;
            } while (j % i == 0);
            s *= f;
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    if (j > 1) {
        s *= 1 + j;
    }
    return s;
}

int sum_of_proper_divisors(int n) {
    return sum_of_divisors(n) - n;
}

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    if (scanf("%d %d", &m, &n) != 2) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = m; i < n; ++i) {
        int j = sum_of_proper_divisors(i);
        if (i < j && j <= n && sum_of_proper_divisors(j) == i) {
            printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 amicable-numbers.c 
>
> $ time echo 1 100000 | ./a.out 
> 220 284
> 1184 1210
> 2620 2924
> 5020 5564
> 6232 6368
> 10744 10856
> 12285 14595
> 17296 18416
> 63020 76084
> 66928 66992
> 67095 71145
> 69615 87633
> 79750 88730
>
> real  0m0.032s
> user  0m0.028s
> sys   0m0.000s
>
> $ time echo 1 1000000 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 40
>
> real  0m0.720s
> user  0m0.716s
> sys   0m0.000s
>
> $ time echo 1 10000000 | ./a.out | wc -l
> 100
>
> real  0m17.049s
> user  0m17.044s
> sys   0m0.000s
> ```